# Sorting a vector of maps by a value in map against a vector of those values - Clojure

Tags: clojure

We have `sort-by` in clojure to sort values against a vector or map.

For example, if I have a vector that I want to sort against:

```
(def ^:const sort-numbers ["one" "two" "three" "four" "five"])
```

And I have this random vector with disordered values, something like:

```
(def numbers ["two" "three" "one" "four"])
```

Now, they could be sorted by:

```
(sort-by #(.indexOf sort-numbers %) numbers)
```

Again, now I have this vector of maps:

```
(def numbers-map [{:one 1 :two 2 :three 3} 
                  {:one 4 :two 4 :three 3}
                  {:one 3 :two 2 :three 1}])
```

If I want to sort the `numbers-map` by the value of the key `:one` against all the maps in the vector,

```
(sort-by :one numbers-map)
```

would do, and it would give me the following result:

```
({:one 1, :two 2, :three 3} {:one 3, :two 2, :three 1} {:one 4, :two 4, :three 3})
```

Now, what I need is a combination of these.
That is, I need to sort the `numbers-map` by the value of the key `:one`, but I don't want them to be auto-sorted, but rather sort them against a specified vector of all possible values of `:one` that I already have somewhere.

How can that be achieved?

Comment: Can you show us the _specified vector of all possible values of :one_ that you have somewhere? Along with the expected output for a given input?

Comment: @jas Let's just use an arbitrary vector for example: 
```(def ^:const one-values [10 5 1 2 4 3]```. 

So instead of auto-sorting in the incremental way,  it should be doing it based on the index of those values in the vector `one-values`.

Comment: @jas And the expected output by sorting it against the vector would be:

```({:one 1, :two 2, :three 3}, {:one 4, :two 4, :three 3}, {:one 3 :two 2 :three 1})```

Note the order in which `1`, `4`, and `3` appear in the vector `one-values`.

Comment: Don't use `^:const` just because you don't expect the value to change. That is the expectation of *all* values in Clojure, so instead `^:const` means something else. To the compiler it basically means "I encourage you to inline this value every time it is used", which is something you rarely want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This allows you to do that

```clj
(def numbers-maps [{:one 1 :two 2 :three 3} 
                   {:one 4 :two 4 :three 3}
                   {:one 3 :two 2 :three 1}])

(def sort-numbers [4 3 2 1])

(sort-by #(.indexOf sort-numbers (:one %))
         numbers-maps)

({:one 4, :two 4, :three 3}
 {:one 3, :two 2, :three 1}
 {:one 1, :two 2, :three 3})
```

Here is another example:

```clj
(def numbers-maps [{:one 6, :two 9, :three 9}
                   {:one 9, :two 9, :three 8}
                   {:one 7, :two 6, :three 2}
                   {:one 4, :two 4, :three 5}
                   {:one 9, :two 1, :three 5}
                   {:one 1, :two 8, :three 8}
                   {:one 8, :two 3, :three 9}
                   {:one 8, :two 4, :three 5}
                   {:one 4, :two 8, :three 1}
                   {:one 5, :two 1, :three 1}])

(def one-values [10 5 1 2 4 3])

(sort-by #(.indexOf one-values (:one %))
         numbers-maps)

({:one 6, :two 9, :three 9}
 {:one 9, :two 9, :three 8}
 {:one 7, :two 6, :three 2}
 {:one 9, :two 1, :three 5}
 {:one 8, :two 3, :three 9}
 {:one 8, :two 4, :three 5}
 {:one 5, :two 1, :three 1}
 {:one 1, :two 8, :three 8}
 {:one 4, :two 4, :three 5}
 {:one 4, :two 8, :three 1})
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought something like that should be doing it but somehow missed this form. :D

Comment: Efficiency tip - indexOf does a linear scan through the vector, so this could be slow if the vector is large and you are often looking up indexes of the 1000-th element, for example.  In some cases it might be faster to pre-calculate a Clojure map from values to their relative indexes, i.e. it gives for each possible value you want to pass to `#(.indexOf one-values my-val)` that `my-val` as a key, and the index value as the associated value, so that this can be determined faster than the linear scan.